# How it will effects the database if I change a field type from varchar to char in larger size tables of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have existed a database where primary key as varchar type in one table.
I found that this degrade the query performance. Now I want to change the data type from varchar to char. My question is if I change the table how it will affect the entire database. **Note that, in the table there are more than 3 million records stored now.**

Is there anything I need to worry regarding this.
Thanks in advance for any helps and suggestions.

Comment: How is `char` better than `varchar` for your application? What is the data format of your primary key?

Comment: Note that generally changing the key column's type in any DBMS requires a table re-creation, a very expensive operation, though the time it takes to recreate a table depends on the size of each row and what indexes exist on the table.

Comment: "I found that **this** degrade the query performance." --- how exactly did you find that?

Comment: char will take up more space than varchar, but won't make any speed difference on query if it is a key. A primary key search will be fast regardless of type, although int may be faster than any string type.

Comment: We used a id generation formula for primary key. For each id we retrieve max value from sub string and increment it with 1. Then insert the record. I expect that if i use char type then i will get little bit performance improvement for this operation and also select join query. Am i the right way ?

Comment: @karim_fci Sounds like a lot of extra work.  MySQL already has a very efficient means to have an automatically incremented ID, [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html).  Why not use that?

Comment: procedure analyse() show that the table primary key optimal_fieldtype is  char instead of varchar. @zerkms

Comment: @karim_fci: not sure what "procedure analyse()". Is it some 3rd party thing? How reliable is it?

Comment: It is core functionality of mysql, not third party things.

Comment: It is core functionality of mysql, not third party things. ANALYSE() examines the result from a query and returns an analysis of the results that suggests optimal data types for each column that may help reduce table sizes. To obtain this analysis, append PROCEDURE ANALYSE to the end of a SELECT statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html @zerkms

Comment: @karim_fci so take your data, change the type and compare. For me the advice looks stupid.

Comment: @zerkms   Sorry! i am not advising you. I just giving answer of your question. 
Thanks a lot for your endeavor for helping me

Answer (score 2):

[The MySQL docs list differences between CHAR and VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html), here are the significant ones.

- Truncation.

  - For VARCHAR columns, trailing spaces in excess of the column length are truncated prior to insertion and a warning is generated, regardless of the SQL mode in use.
  - For CHAR columns, truncation of excess trailing spaces from inserted values is performed silently regardless of the SQL mode.
- Padding.

  - When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed.
  - VARCHAR values are not padded when they are stored. Trailing spaces are retained when values are stored and retrieved, in conformance with standard SQL.

I seriously doubt that switching from VARCHAR to CHAR will have any effect on query performance, and will probably take up more space.  I also doubt having your primary key be a string is affecting performance.  More likely there is a lack of indexing or poorly written queries.  Check with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html).

In general, having your primary key be anything but an auto incremented integer type (INT or BIGINT) is bad table design.  A primary key which is a string implies that string carries significance, and you will be tempted to change it.  Changing a primary key causes all sorts of problems.

Instead, add an integer primary key field with [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) to your table and use that.

```
ALTER TABLE whatever
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Be sure to alter any tables which refer to this one to use the new key.